# sql,vb error "no row at position 0"

Tags: sql, vb.net

I get the message "there is no row at position 0" in the form with the following code:

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdSave.Click
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim xid As Integer
    Dim xQTY(0) As Integer
    Dim xQTY_ID(0) As Integer
    Dim xCount As Integer
    Dim xCounter_ID(0) As Integer
    'Dim sqlstrx(5) As String
    xid = 0
    **If lstitems.Items.Count > 0 Then**
        If Split(Me.Text, " - ")(1) = "Add" Then
            sqlSTR = "INSERT INTO orders (CustID, Cust_Name, order_date) " & _
                     "VALUES (" & txtcustid.Text & ", " _
                            & "'" & txtcustname.Text & "', " _
                            & "'" & Format(dttoday.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy") & "')"
            ExecuteSQLQuery(sqlSTR)
            sqlSTR = "SELECT * FROM orders ORDER BY order_no DESC"
            ExecuteSQLQuery(sqlSTR)
            xid = sqlDT.Rows(0)("order_no")
            For i = 0 To lstitems.Items.Count - 1
                sqlSTR = "INSERT INTO orders_detail (order_no, idDrug, DrugName, Unit_Cost, qty, totalcost) " & _
                         "VALUES (" & xid & ", " _
                                    & lstitems.Items(i).Text & ", " _
                              & "'" & lstitems.Items(i).SubItems(1).Text & "', " _
                              & "'" & lstitems.Items(i).SubItems(2).Text & "', " _
                                    & lstitems.Items(i).SubItems(3).Text & ", " _
                                    & lstitems.Items(i).SubItems(4).Text & ", " _
                                    & lstitems.Items(i).SubItems(5).Text & ")"
                ExecuteSQLQuery(sqlSTR)
```

Error highlights the bold line.

Comment: There is no bold line... I assume it's xid = sqlDT.Rows(0)("order_no")?

Comment: yeah there,sorry for the error

Comment: Where did you declare `sqlDT`? Is that a `DataTable`? And you need to fill data to DataTable `sqlDT`.

Comment: where is sqlDT declared?

Comment: where did you fill `sqlDT datatable` ????

Comment: sqlDT is declared in a module

Comment: in the executesqlquery function

Comment: If this is to become a real application and not just a test, you should start using [`SqlParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx) ASAP. Please look at the section "You are prone to SQL Injection attacks" in this link: [Database - Why should I use Parameters instead of putting values into my SQL string?](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?548787-Database-Why-should-I-use-Parameters-instead-of-putting-values-into-my-SQL-string).

Comment: Ok,i will look into that,am still a student though;new to programming stuff

Answer (score 1):

your code missing fill for your dataTable

Try this :

```
        Dim sqlAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlSTR, yourconnctionstring)
        sqlAdapter.Fill(sqlDT)
        If sqlDT.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        xid = sqlDT.Rows(0)("order_no")
        End If
```

Comment: i know get an error: InvalidArgument=Value of '5' is not valid for 'index'. which highlights the code where you insert data into orders_detail

Comment: From  'sqlSTR = "INSERT INTO orders_detail (order_no, idDrug, DrugName,   Unit _Cost, qty, totalcost) " & _...to ..& lstitems.Items(i).SubItems(5).Text & ")"'

Comment: are you sure thier is subitems(5) in postion 5???
start subitems from 0 to 4 not from 1 to 5 .

Comment: did this help you? if not tell me .

Comment: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)---That is the error and it highlights the code:sqlAdapter.Fill(sqlDT),and my connection string is ok btw

Comment: This is SQL connection error message. Can you show me the connection you use

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
   Dim sqlAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlSTR, yourconnctionstring)
    sqlAdapter.Fill(sqlDT)
    If sqlDT.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    xid = sqlDT.Rows(0)("order_no")
    End If
            'write your code here.....
```

Comment: I think this is VB .NET code. No square bracket `[]` and no `;` needed!

Comment: The function **ExecuteSQLQuery** resets and fills the datatable,so i'd be repeating my self i think